# Why Private data member

Tags: java

Why do we keep data member of a class as private?
Answer-- so that it can not be accessed from outside the class
But, 
Since I am creating class or classes so I am responsible for data members then I can keep every data member as public... But then also it's not a good practice ,why? 
Teacher says you should keep data member as private.

Comment: You want each class to be in control of its own fields.  For example, you might want to make sure a particular field is never null.  If the field is public, anyone can set it to anything, including null;  but if it’s private and can only be changed through public methods, those methods can reject attempts to set the field to null, such as by throwing an IllegalArgumentException.  This practice is known as encapsulation.

Comment: Note that the "anyone" in VGR's comment include yourself, it's very easy when reusing a class 3 months later to forget its implementation details. Forcing yourself to use its methods that handle all the details make it easier to ensure you won't misuse it.

Comment: Suppose I am creating my software.then again I will create my own classes ..then why other will try to access data member and how.

Comment: @dnsiv Private variables aren't a valid security measure because there are other ways of reading that memory. `private` doesn't even guarantee that it won't be read from within the same application - you can use reflection to read the value.

Answer (score 3):

For the same reason cars keep all the knobs and levers inside the engine bay and do not expose them to the user interface (i.e. the dashboard). It's to keep stuff simple and make obvious to the user/observer what you should touch to operate the class. This benefits external users and also the future you, when you'll have long forgotten how to use your own class :-)

Making methods and variables private is not a way to "protect" them from evil programmers out there (example: "hey, I'm the only programmer here, why I should make the variables private?"), it's a way to "explain" to others and mostly yourself what the class is all about and hide away all the complexity, exposing only the bare minimum to use the class itself

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at this concept called Encapsulation.

You make variables private so that you can restrict the access level to those variables. For example: you can set a variable to be read only so that you accidentally don't write into it.

> But, Since I am creating class or classes so I am responsible for data members then I can keep every data member as public

Even if you are building a project yourself, encapsulation should be followed as it helps you to stay in control and put forth a well defined rule for your variables.

Here are its advantages in a nutshell:

1. It gives you more control over your variables
2. It helps you achieve data hiding
3. It makes it easy to test

Further reading:
https://www.javatpoint.com/encapsulation